# Use of a static java object for a Software Component

Tags: java, multithreading, components, static-methods

I have a question about how to approach a certain design. I am creating a chat client a application and my implementation has several GUIs, One for Login screen, 2nd for register screen, third for the chat GUI. I want to have one thread starting when when the login screen starts that is the ConnectionHandler, basically it will send all commands to the server, based on a SynchronizedQue which i want to wrap in a MessageQue object which will be a static, one off object. The idea is to have this thread running through out the lifetime of the application.

Basically the login screen will send a message to the SynchronizedQue and then the ConnectionHandler reads that it has been updated, takes the message to a socket and sends it away.

Is it a correct object oriented approach to this case? I have read that static objects, variables etc are not a correct object oriented approach. Basically the question is about a design philosophy for implementing a one off components that sit in memory and other classes communicate with it.

EDIT:
Another idea that just popped into my mind at the time of writing this is to put the static object MessageQue in to a MessegeQueHandler class, so the MessegeQueHandler class can be created at will but the messege que will exist in the background which could be a little bit more object oriented.

Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: I don't really understand your design, but `static` variables and `static` methods (including constructors!) limit your options for testing your code (especially for _unit testing_), and they'll make extra work for you if you ever want to re-use your code or, change the architecture of your system.  All that must be balanced against the fact that there may be more up-front work for you to create a non-`static` design in the first place.

Comment: @james Well my design is basically 3 GUis: Login screen which leads to either a register screen or a chat app screen with two text boxes. I don't want to pass the connection arround but have one thread to start at the start of the aplication which will read a SynchronizedQue collection, I want to make the SynchronizedQue static so i can add messeges to server from every GUI, without creating any objects because I would have to create a new list everytime. Would there be a better aproach to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is the [Singleton Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) and is a very common pattern used in both OO design and other paradigms. So yes, it is OK to use it in OO design.